# How to implement Paypal Express Checkout API?

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

I am working on Cakephp e-commerce academic project. I need to implement Paypal Express checkout API for online transaction. I don't know how to do this, please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: You will probably need to show some code.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Not just an error message, but what is the actual problem? What are you not able to do in the code? You will need to be able to program, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

They have a nice wizard:

https://www.paypal-labs.com/

https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/

Comment: Both links are broken.